# jQuery, run Fancybox on page load

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have jQuery Isotope running correctly so it makes a nice list of links and when a user clicks a link it pulls up an iframe within Fancybox as expected.  I want to add to this so i can have Fancybox run when the page loads.  What do i need to add in?

User Flow:

```
[user on another page] -> [user clicks link] -> [redirect to this page/code which runs Fancybox on pageload]
```

Current Isotope code:

```
<div class="portfolioFilter">
          Filter by: 
                <a href="#" data-filter="*" class="button3">Show All</a>
                <a href="#" data-filter=".A" class="button3">A</a>
                <a href="#" data-filter=".B" class="button3">B</a>
                ...
</div>
<div class="portfolioContainer">
     <div class="A isospacing">
          <a href="page.html" class="various" data-fancybox-type="iframe" id="S54"><span class="description">John Doe</span></a>  
          <a href="page2.html" class="various" data-fancybox-type="iframe" id="S55"><span class="description">Jane Doe</span></a>
          ...
      </div>
</div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
        var $container = $('.portfolioContainer');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: '*',
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
        }).trigger("click");

        $('.portfolioFilter a').click(function(){
            $('.portfolioFilter .current').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');

            var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            $container.isotope({
                filter: selector,
                animationOptions: {
                    duration: 750,
                    easing: 'linear',
                    queue: false
                }
             });
             return false;
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI,

I solved it using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fancybox({
        'width': '40%',
        'height': '40%',
        'autoScale': true,
        'transitionIn': 'fade',
        'transitionOut': 'fade',
        'type': 'iframe',
        'href': 'http://www.Website.com/Details'
    });
```

});